# Declaring a TypeScript function with properties

Tags: typescript

I'm writing [a library](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is) and I want to port it to TypeScript.

Currently it looks something like this:

#### File *index.js*

```
const is = value => {
    // ... Do some returns here
}

is.number = x => typeof x === 'number'
is.bla = x => typeof x === 'bla'
```

And so on.

I have wrote an interface describing `is` and all its methods.

```
type TypeQueryMethod = (val: any) => boolean;

interface Is {
    (val: any): string;
    undefined: TypeQueryMethod;
    null: TypeQueryMethod;
    // ...
}
```

When I try to mark `is` with the type: `const is: Is = value => ...`

It throws an error:

```
Type '(value: any) => string' is not assignable to type 'Is'.
Property 'undefined' is missing in type '(value: any) => string'.
```

Which makes sense because the declaration of the object is split.

How do you construct such an object that is both a method, and has methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update for TypeScript 3.1+

TypeScript 3.1 introduced support for [declaring properties on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions), to allow you to do this the way you were doing it to begin with:

```
const is: Is = (val: any) => typeof val; // okay
is.undefined = (val: any) => typeof val === 'undefined'; 
is.null = (val: any) => (val === null)
```

---

For TypeScript versions before 3.1:

If you want to make the type checker happy, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to return a fully-formed `Is` object without building it in stages:

```
const is: Is = Object.assign(
  (val: any) => typeof val,
  {
    undefined: (val: any) => typeof val === 'undefined',
    null: (val: any) => (val === null)
    // ...
  }
);
```

Of course, if you don't want to change the structure of your code, then you can do as @Saravana suggests and use a [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) to just inform the type checker that `is` is definitely an `Is`, even though it technically isn't one until you're done building it.

Either way works, but I prefer the `Object.assign()` method because the type checker will warn you if you neglect to implement something:

```
// error, "undefined" is missing
const is: Is = Object.assign(
  (val: any) => typeof val,
  {
    null: (val: any) => (val === null)
    // ...
  }
);
```

while the type assertion method will not:

```
const is = ((val: any) => typeof val) as any as Is;
is.null = (val) => val === null;
// no error
```

whereas the type assertion method will not.  It's up to you.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEUCuEBOICyFgAsD2AJlALxQAUAbgIYA2AXFFQHYgCUJAfFAEZ540RmAbgBQIgJZNgaAGZUAxtACSAZygBvEVHLV6jFqwYrgqSQHNR2pEwIQZkiAQZxIyNJmz4ClqEyQ09F0QUdCxcQlEAXzF5PCZjKHEVBlUSHVoGZjZOKFBIPBkoXSEoAHpSqDwAayoQCRUAOmtbeyZHNMoM-WziLjyIAqLaEmJSAHJmuwcCMdEkhr8Ajt1MgxzOmhHSRZpWMSYqAFsIFTAFaAAFVAgKcTwkFQA1NBU7pg0tKFj44ETkqFSpAA8twAFYQeTABpUFSvMxMMifbQbVY9PrwQa6AA0SI+2nxUEmrUcDBR3XYvVyGMKui2UAmNimbRmOIJ2h2pJW5PWtNG238u1x2nKUAaYtx0W0rFEn2+CSSACEqE4AWpgWCIVCYXCEWUKmhUHhULiyVkKej8jTaKz8Zo2b4BZyumaecM+Q6Ant7SKxQ0JZ9pWJtHLfkkAIKwtDABWGqoQd6kMimtaU-qY2jsGHdRhqVQ+cOR1DR2PxhYC5YZnK80Yemg+EVMPBQA1GsQiSJAA)

Comment: The Object.assign approach is just infinitely better than the type assertion version.

Comment: I don't get it... this answer just got accepted after four years, even though it and the question were obsolete since TypeScript 3.1.  ‍♂️  Oh well!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot implement a function as well as its properties at the same time. You can define the function first and assert it to `Is` and define the rest of the methods:

```
const is = ((val: any) => typeof (val)) as any as Is;

is.null = (val) => true;
is.undefined = (val) => true;
```

Or use a factory function to create `Is`:

```
function createIs(): Is {
    const is = ((val: any) => {
        return "";
    }) as Is;
    is.null = (val) => true;
    is.undefined= (val) => true;
    return is;
}

const is: Is = createIs();
```

Comment: You should be able to use `Object.assign()` to create an `Is` with no type assertions.

Comment: @jcalz `Object.assign` is only available when the target version is es6 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do, is to provide the properties as optional:

```
type TypeQueryMethod = (val: any) => boolean;

interface Is {
    (val: any): string;
    undefined?: TypeQueryMethod;
    null?: TypeQueryMethod;
    ...
}
```

And now you can safely define it as `Is`:

```
const is: Is = value => ...
```